# Python. не могу заставить программу говорить

Tags: python, text-to-speech

решил попробовать программировать на питон. проблема на скрине. подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема и как решить

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import os
import sys
import webbrowser

def talk(words):
     print('words')
     os.system("say "+words)

talk("Привет, спроси что у меня что-либо")
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1240854/edit))

Comment: откуда взялась консольная команда say? Единственный используемый импорт это os остальные для чего?

Comment: пишется с заделом на распознавание голоса, для этого остальные

Comment: Специально для вас нашёл решение. Кстати этот способ работает только на маках вроде бы

Answer (score 1):

```
import pyttsx3
 

speak_engine = pyttsx3.init()
# функции
def speak(what):
   
    print( what )
    speak_engine.say( what )
    speak_engine.runAndWait()
    speak_engine.stop()
 

 

speak("Ваш текст")
```

Вот вам этот код в помощь, но перед этим впишите в консоль следующие команды:

1. `pip install pyttsx3`
2. `pip install PyAudio`

Comment: спасибо, но у меня не мак, а при попытке подгрузить pyaudio выдает ошибку

Comment: Щас, вам скажу. Как действовать

Comment: Цитирую:
Сначала установите Xcode. Затем перезагрузите компьютер. Затем выполните команды последовательно, ```xcode-select --install
brew remove portaudio
brew install portaudio
pip3 install pyaudio```
Итак, чтобы уточнить, Xcode устанавливается через App Store. Для некоторых установок требуются инструменты командной строки Xcode, для других - нет. Я включаю его здесь, чтобы быть в безопасности. Вам также, вероятно, не нужно удалять и переустанавливать формулу через Homebrew, я сделал это, чтобы убедиться, что проблем не будет.

Comment: Изменить: мне сказали, что Homebrew требует Xcode. Поэтому просто запустите
`xcode-select --install` https://overcoder.net/q/576270/%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-pyaudio-%D0%BD%D0%B0-mac-python-3 вот исходник